# nav2d autonomous exploration

Tags: ros, navigation, sensor, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every problems before fixed:

EDIT 6: Hi friends!! I have just fixed every problems with your help.
So now my robot moves with StartMapping and with StartExplorer, but not really well...

I think that it do good StartMapping but when I do StartExplorer, my robot explores just a few second and it gets stuck in a wall.
I think that this problem is for some .yaml parameters.

But I modify a lot of parameters to check if it does a good navigatiion and alwais it gets stuck. Which parameters have I to modify or what I can do???

Thanka  lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235767/nav2d-autonomous-exploration/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2016-06-01**:
You are asking very basic questions. You should start by reading and understanding tutorials about topics and launch files. After that, try again by yourself (and probably you will be successful). If even then is not working, came back with a more specific question/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The topic "cmd_vel" should be connected to you robot driver for motion commands and "scan" to your laser sensor driver for scan data samples. In the latest release, the parameters for the services are no longer needed, so you can just use them like: "rosservice call /StartExploration".

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-01**:
@Sebastian Kasperski thanks a lot for answering. I have just edited first post with the current error.!

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-01**:
For the second part you need to make a tf tree. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20(C%2B%2B))

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-01**:
@Icehawk101 I have just fixed that error. Now the error is the next when I call rosservice StartExploration:

[ERROR]  Exploration failed, could not get current position.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-01**:
You should make a second edit to your question with the new information.

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-01**:
@Icehawk101 Done!!

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-06-02**:
In your launch file are 2 different mapping nodes and 2 different navigation nodes, this will not work.

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-02**:
I have just editted post! @Sebastian Kasperski

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-06-02**:
You also don't need amcl when using slam. Please check the nav2d tutorials. Does your robot move when you send something to cmd_vel? And check with rostopic echo if something is even send on this topic. With just "The robot doesn't move", nobody can help you.

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-02**:
@Sebastian Kasperski I have just eddited with more information!! thanks!!

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-02**:
@Sebastian Kasperski It gives me this error as well:
LaserRangeFinder::Validate() - LocalizedRangeScan contains 672 range readings, expected 673

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-06-02**:
Your laser scans contain angle_min, angle_max and angle_increment, which should match the supplied number of readings. [num_readings = ((angle_max - angle_min) / angle_increment) + 1] Maybe your laser driver sets these values incorrectly.

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-06-02**:
It looks like the array holding the range data has a spot with a NULL value for some reason. What driver are you using for the laser?

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2016-06-03**:
@Sebastian Kasperski @Icehawk101 Hello my friends. I have just edited the post!!! Thanks again,